# designing program with a while loop

Tags: pseudocode

We are learning while loops and Im not sure how to do this in this problem:

At one college, the tuition for a full-time student is $6,000 per semester. It has been announced that the tuition will increase by 2 percent each year for the next five years. Design a program with a while loop that displays the projected semester tuition amount for the next five years.

I would normally do it like this

```
Module main ( )

Declare Integer total = 0
Declare Integer counter

Set tuition = 6000

For counter = 1 To 5
Set tuition = 2 * tuition + tuition * .02
End For

Display “The amount you pay in 5 years of tuition is “, tuition


End Module
```

Comment: What is your question? Is this not behaving as expected? Also you left the assignment #5 in there. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I just have to write out the pseudocode. We are not actually coding the program for real. Im just not sure how I replace for with while